# How can I use NSDateFormatter to get the string "Yesterday"?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to format my `NSDate` so that a date that occurred yesterday will be displayed as "Yesterday'. Can this be done using `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: This is totally a real question with a real answer to it, which Breakpoint has provided.

Comment: This question should not have been closed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use,

`[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES]`

to indicate if an output of date components need to be printed in a phrase or not, as "Today", "Tomorrow" etc.
The output phrases however, depend on the `locale` set for the `dateFormatter`

Read through the **Managing Natural Language Support** of the [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further details.